# ui.services.connection.api.PartnerConnectionException: INVALID_FIELD: salesforce

Tags: campaign, campaign-member, owd

I gave permissions on Campaign to some profile - Read, Create, Edit

And on OWD I gave to the Campaign member -  Controlled by Campaign.

When I entered Campaigns from a user in that profile- I see the Campaign, But I can't see the Campaign member.

What I do see is the next Error message :

> ui.services.connection.api.PartnerConnectionException: INVALID_FIELD:
>   LastModifiedById, LastModifiedDate, LastName, LeadOrContactId, Status,
>   SystemModstamp ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:117 No such column
>   'LeadOrContactId' on entity 'CampaignMember'. If you are attempting to
>   use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field
>   name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the
>   appropriate names.

The profile have marked as a Marketing user.

From the sysAdmin Profile, I can see data.

And I couldn't find the field in LeadOrContactId on the Campaign Member object to check the FLS, But I did find that field in the workbench.

I couldn't find anything when I entered that error message to a search on google.

Any Idea?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although we gave public on OWD for Contacts and Leads we should give Read permission for Contact and Lead also for that profile.

That was the problem...

Thanks.